# How to pass a generic object as a methods parameter

Tags: c#, generics

This may be a very basic question, but it still gets me confused (and Google can't help) ;-) How can I pass a generic object as a parameter to a function?

For example I have a class `CoolGeneric<T>`

Now I need a method `DoSomethingWithAGeneric(CoolGeneric g)`.
Here the compiler keeps on complaining that a concrete type parameter is necessary. But the method should work with all kinds of type parameters!

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply :

```
DoSomethingWithAGeneric<T>(CoolGeneric<T> g)
```

Or if the method is within a class declaring the generic type :

```
class MyClass<T> {

    DoSomethingWithAGeneric(CoolGeneric<T> g)


}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want:

```
DoSomethingWithAGeneric<T>(CoolGeneric<T> g)
```

the compiler will usually detect the `T` automatically (generic type inference), so the caller doesn't normally have to specify it; i.e.

```
CoolGeneric<int> foo = ...
DoSomethingWithAGeneric(foo);
```

which is (usually) identical to:

```
DoSomethingWithAGeneric<int>(foo);
```